# take first occurrence of data from a query postgresql

Tags: postgresql

We have a system that has item_numbers and scans for those item numbers.
I need a query that returns the 1st scan record for each item.

```
SELECT  item_number, dis.scan_datetime, dli.item_sequence_no
FROM distribution_stop_information dsi 
join distribution_line_items dli on dsi.unique_id_no = dli.unique_id_no 
join distribution_item_scans dis on stop_unique_id_no = dli.unique_id_no
WHERE dis.scan_type = 9 and (dli.item_sequence_no = dis.item_sequence_no )  and
dsi.unique_id_no = 245769
```

this returns a dataset that includes a record for every scan for each item:

> "132275190501001" "2019-05-02 06:07:44"   "1"
>
> "132275190501001" "2019-05-02 07:04:42"   "1"
>
> "089275190501001" "2019-05-02 06:07:54"   "2"
>
> "089275190501001" "2019-05-02 07:04:52"   "2"

So what I need the above to return would be the first scan for the first item, and the first scan for the second item etc...

Comment: The sample data you posted indicate that the only difference between the items is the date and you only want to pick the row with the minimum date. Is this so or there are cases where the pair item_number and item_sequence_no will be different for one item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use the 'distinct on' two fields, along with a change in my join.

```
SELECT distinct on (dis.item_sequence_no, item_number) item_number, dis.scan_datetime
FROM distribution_stop_information dsi 
join distribution_line_items dli on dsi.unique_id_no = dli.unique_id_no 
join distribution_item_scans dis on stop_unique_id_no = dli.unique_id_no
WHERE (dis.scan_type = 2) and (dli.item_sequence_no = dis.item_sequence_no )  and
(dsi.route_date = '4/30/2019' and dsi.company_no = '11' and customer_no = '1000' and dli.company_no = '11')
```